# How to access Project Properties from NetBeans Plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins, project-properties

I am developing a NetBeans Plugin which should be able to change the encoding of a NetBeans Project. In my plugin I have a reference to an instance of `org.netbeans.api.project.Project` but I still don't know how I can read the "Encoding" property of that project.

Can I read the "Project Properties" with the `ProjectUtil` class or do I need a lookup on each `FileObject`?

Here is a screenshot of the property which I want to read & write:

[image]